# NSURLRequest to Make Sure that the URL is Available

Tags: ios

I am using the following code to make sure that if the URL is available:

```
NSString *const URL = @"http://some_url/";

-(BOOL) isURLReachable
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response
                                      error:&error];

    // just for testing

    NSLog(@"checking response!");

    return [response statusCode] == 200;
}
```

I can only reach the url when I am connected to the company's network which is okay. But when I go outside or on my 4G network I still get status code 200. Further investigation revealed that if the URL is not available then Tmobile searches for the URL and displays in a search view and returns status code 200. I do not want that? If the URL is not reachable then I would like to know that it is not reachable. How can I proceed?

Comment: Check the returned page content to ensure it's what you're expecting? If your ISP (Tmobile/etc) is returning valid 200s, those sites are still "reachable" in an application sense.

Comment: @admdrew Thanks! Yeah tmobile is returning their custom page with valid 200. I think if it does not find the page then it assumes that I am searching for that page and display a search page on tmobile website.

Comment: Have you looked at this sample project from Apple? https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability